# Parsing HTML Table in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack, html-table

I have an html page which contains a table and i want to parse that table in C# windows form

> http://www.mufap.com.pk/payout-report.php?tab=01

this is the webpage i want to parse i have tried

```
> Foreach(Htmlnode a in document.getelementbyname("tr"))
{
    richtextbox1.text=a.innertext;
}
```

i have tried some thing like this but it wont give me in tabular form as i am simply printing all trs so please help me regarding this thanx
sorry for my english.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Using [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string page = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.mufap.com.pk/payout-report.php?tab=01");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);

List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='mydata']")
            .Descendants("tr")
            .Skip(1)
            .Where(tr=>tr.Elements("td").Count()>1)
            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanx L.B. After removing the [@class='mydata'] It works as generic code...Perfect....

Comment: if the table is paging, then how to go to the next page by scraping?

Comment: @Dark_Knight Have you seen `?tab=01` in the url?

Comment: I am just getting "Test Street\tTest Loc\tTest town\ttest\ttest\ttest\ttest\ttest\ttest\ttest\ttest\ttest" using this as one string (as only have one row) shouldn't this be in a nested list?

Comment: Worked for me. You can use "//table[2]" to get the second node of <table>

Comment: Adding that for a Selenium scrapping, just add WebDriver.PageSource instead of the variable page.

Answer (score 17):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")) {
    ///This is the table.    
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr")) {
    ///This is the row.
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td")) {
            ///This the cell.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i want to show each cell in a listview control formated as html table in the webpage

Answer (score 4):

Late on this, but a way to do what you ask using plain vanilla C# code may be the following

```
/// <summary>
/// parses a table and returns a list containing all the data with columns separated by tabs
/// e.g.: records = getTable(doc, 0);
/// </summary>
/// <param name="doc">HtmlDocument to work with</param>
/// <param name="number">table index (base 0)</param>
/// <returns>list containing the table data</returns>
public List<string> getTableData(HtmlDocument doc, int number)
{
  HtmlElementCollection tables = doc.GetElementsByTagName("table");
  int idx=0;
  List<string> data = new List<string>();

  foreach (HtmlElement tbl in tables)
  {
    if (idx++ == number)
    {
      data = getTableData(tbl);
      break;
    }
  }
  return data;
}

/// <summary>
/// parses a table and returns a list containing all the data with columns separated by tabs
/// e.g.: records = getTable(getElement(doc, "table", "id", "table1"));
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tbl">HtmlElement table to work with</param>
/// <returns>list containing the table data</returns>
public List<string> getTableData(HtmlElement tbl)
{
  int nrec = 0;
  List<string> data = new List<string>();
  string rowBuff;

  HtmlElementCollection rows = tbl.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
  HtmlElementCollection cols;
  foreach (HtmlElement tr in rows)
  {
    cols = tr.GetElementsByTagName("td");
    nrec++;
    rowBuff = nrec.ToString();
    foreach (HtmlElement td in cols)
    {
      rowBuff += "\t" + WebUtility.HtmlDecode(td.InnerText);
    }
    data.Add(rowBuff);
  }

  return data;
}
```

the above will allow you to extract data from a table either by using the table "index" inside the page (useful for unnamed tables) or by passing the "table" HtmlElement to the function (faster but only useful for named tables); notice that I choose to return a "List" as the result and separating the various columns data using a tab character; you may easily change the code to return the data in whatever other format you prefer