# Telerik grid binding From Html table

Tags: asp.net

i have some data in html (html table--)

```
<TABLE SUMMARY=""><CAPTION>welcome</CAPTION><THEAD><TR><TH>Bonus </TH><TH>Points Required</TH><TH>Valid for</TH><TH>Min Deposit</TH><TH>Bonus Code</TH></TR></THEAD><TFOOT><TR><TD /><TD /><TD /><TD /><TD /></TR></TFOOT><TBODY><TR class="odd"><TD>5 Bonus</TD><TD>350</TD><TD>60 Days</TD><TD>10</TD><TD>Welcome25</TD></TR><TR><TD>00 Bonus</TD><TD>1200</TD><TD>60 Days</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>Welcome100</TD></TR><TR class="odd"><TD>250 Bonus</TD><TD>3000</TD><TD>60 Days</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>Welcome250</TD></TR><TR><TD>500 Bonus</TD><TD>5500</TD><TD>60 Days</TD><TD>100</TD><TD>Welcome500</TD></TR><TR class="odd"><TD>100 Bonus</TD><TD>10</TD><TD>60 Days</TD><TD>250</TD><TD>Welcome1000</TD></TR><TR><TD>2000 Bonus</TD><TD>18000</TD><TD>42 Days</TD><TD>500</TD><TD>Welcome2000</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

format and its stored to a strong . now Can i bind this to telerik grid. or if it is possible with converting this string to xml. I tried it with online xml converted xml but failed.

Regards,
Sivajith S.

Comment: You need to get it to a .net data structure, probably IEnumerable at least, so use html agility pack and convert it to a list with linq  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005098/parsing-html-table-in-c-sharp

Comment: k thank you..let me do that..