# scrape table from web site

Tags: c#, windows

i want to scrape table from this site : http://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=INR&amount=1

[I want this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAA6u.jpg)

and i want to do  this with C# Windows Application 
I use web request and response and it shows me all page source code
how can I pick that specific table ??

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=INR&amount=1");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        richTextBox.text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: In Windows Application, it is easier to use WebBrowser Control. You can go through all your HtmlDocument and find that table.

Comment: search "scrape web site [c#]", here at stack overflow. 
you'll find the same question asked many, many times

Answer (score 0):

Use C# HTML Agility pack to extract HTML table from your response. It's a table and you can easily extract that table from HTML.

[Parsing HTML Table in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005098/parsing-html-table-in-c-sharp)

May be above link will help you.