# Parse single data elements from HTML tables with C#?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have this code in my main function and I want to parse only the first row of the table (e.g Nov 7, 2017   73.78   74.00   72.32   72.71   17,245,947).

I created a node that concludes only the first row but when I start debugging the node value is null. How can I parse these data and store them for example in a string or in single variables. Is there a way?

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();

        string page = web.DownloadString("https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE:C&ei=7O4nV9GdJcHomAG02L_wCw");

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(page);

        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"prices\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]");

  List<List<string>> node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"prices\"]/table").Descendants("tr").Skip(1).Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1).Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td=>td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList()).ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your selection XPath string has errors. Since `tbody` is a generated node it should not be included in path:

```
//*[@id=\"prices\"]/table/tr[2]
```

While this should read the value HtmlAgilityPack hits another problem `malformed html`. All `<tr>` and `<td>` nodes in parsed text do not have corresponding `</tr>` or `</td>` closing tags and HtmlAgitilityPack fails to select values from table with malformed rows. Therefore, it is necessary to select in first step the whole table:

```
//*[@id=\"prices\"]/table
```

And in the next step either sanitize HTML by adding `</tr>` and `</td>` closing tags and repeat parsing with corrected table or use extracted string to hand parse it - just extract lines 10 to 15 from table string and split them on `>` character. Raw parsing is shown below. Code is tested and working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace GoogleFinanceDataScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();

            string page = web.DownloadString("https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE:C&ei=7O4nV9GdJcHomAG02L_wCw");

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(page);

            var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='prices']/table");

            string outerHtml = node.OuterHtml;
            List<String> data = new List<string>();
            using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(outerHtml))
            {
                for(int i = 0; ; i++)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (i < 9) continue;
                    else if (i < 15)
                    {
                        var dataRawArray = line.Split(new char[] { '>' });
                        var value = dataRawArray[1];
                        data.Add(value);
                    }
                    else break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{data[0]}, {data[1]}, {data[2]}, {data[3]}, {data[4]}, {data[5]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i found this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005098/parsing-html-table-in-c-sharp) and tried to implement as you proposed; it didn't work. P.S i posted it in my code. node still remains null

Comment: I have implemented it as well and in my case everything works as expected. Will paste whole code into answer

Comment: Man i don't know how to thank you! At last works perfectly!!! Do you know any material about web scrapping with c# and ,or html agility??

Comment: Not really. There is a lot about scraping with scripting languages like python.

Comment: By the way, if you find my answer correct you can mark it as an answer to your question.