# Parsing HTML table downloaded from a website using C# and Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

From a Windows WinForms C# application I am trying to read a table from the web site (first page):

> http://www.freeproxylists.net/?c=&pt=&pr=HTTP&a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&u=40

I use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to do this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string page = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.freeproxylists.net/?c=&pt=&pr=HTTP&a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&u=40");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);
```

But doc object does not contains the table I want. I would like to combine this with LINQ, something similiar doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005098/parsing-html-table-in-c-sharp).

What I am trying to do is to read all the table into a list which each item of this list is another list which contains the items below:

> IP Address, Port, Protocol, Anonymity, Country, Region, City, Uptime

How can I do this?

Comment: If you check the downloaded content from WebClient you will see that table is not there. You first need to find out how this data is loaded into page.

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov Yes, so how to do in order to read the table I want? It seems like I have to wait for page loaded but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I guess it is loaded with iframe or javascript. You need to figure it out.

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov How could I know if it is loaded with iframe or javascript? And in case it is loaded with iframe or javascript, how can I retrieve the list of proxies from C#?

Comment: You just go and start digging ;)

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov when I am trying to open your link I got strange captcha screen: [**screenshot link**](https://i.imgur.com/DzT6ldb.png) . Any idea why is this happening?